# Relationship between AMQP inbound channel adapter concurrent-consumers attribute and task executors

Tags: spring-integration

I am using

**Spring Integration 4.1.2.RELEASE**

**Spring AMQP 1.4.3.RELEASE**

I have an AMQP inbound channel adapter and a ThreadPoolTaskExecutor configured like this:

```
<task:executor id="exec.newItems" pool-size="5" />
<int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter
    connection-factory="amqpConnectionFactory" auto-startup="true" 
    queue-names="#{newItemsQueueName}"
    channel="newItems.payloadType.routingChannel"
    message-converter="jsonMessageConverter"
    acknowledge-mode="AUTO" error-channel="errorChannel"
    concurrent-consumers="5"
    mapped-request-headers="*"
    channel-transacted="false"
    task-executor="exec.newItems"
    />
```

I would like to know what the relationship is between the value set for concurrent-consumers in the AMQP inbound channel adapter and the pool-size in the task executor configuration.

Here is what I observed by using the JVM Monitor plugin in Eclipse.

- If concurrent-consumers is greater than pool-size and pool-size is x,
  then x threads are created but they are in the blocked state and
  messages are not processed.
- If concurrent-consumers is equal to pool-size and pool-size is x,
  then x threads are created and messages are processed.
- If concurrent-consumers is less than pool-size and
  concurrent-consumers is y, then y threads are created and messages
  are processed.

I am thinking that concurrent-consumers might be setting the maximum pool size on the executor. Is this an accurate observation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say that your investigation is correct.

Consumers are long-living task with `while(true)` in their `Runnable.run` implementation, hence each of them acquire one Thread from that executor forever (until its death, of course).

The default `Executor` is `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` in the `SimpleMessageListenerContainer`. That means that any new consumer gets it own thread and it doesn't cause blocking issue.

With `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` we really can end up with an issue, when there is no enough threads in the pool for us. And some our consumers won't do their work. The more it may be bad when we share that `taskExecutor` between different components.

It isn't bad idea to use `managed` executor in the application (especially in AS environment), even for this kind of long-living task, but we really should be sure that we have optimal configuration for concurrency.

Comment: Appreciate your cautionary mention of shared `taskExecutors`.